# How to get all entries on a table by many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

How can I get all Groups, by the Person ID in this mysql model? I know I need a join colunm or some Hibernate/JPA black magic, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is the model I'm using in study.

Link with image if is not been displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFzGl.png

[image: Study Model]

To reduce space here are the entities:
[Github Repository](https://github.com/jaoevangelista/studium/tree/master/src/main/java/io/meltedcode/studium/entity)

Comment: Where is your model ??

Comment: I attached the picture in the question, the database modeling

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see any image here..

Comment: @user3003216 check edit, I added another source of image

Comment: Calling a table (or column, or anything) 'group' is just asking for trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following MySQL query will retrieve all groups for a given `idPerson`

```
SELECT g.*
FROM `Group` g
JOIN PersonOnGroup pog on g.idGroup = pog.idGroup
WHERE pog.idPerson = myPersonId
```

I don't know what your hibernate entities look like but something along these lines should work

```
from Group as group
    inner join group.persons as person
    where person.idPerson = 1
```

Comment: I'll try that, also I added a link to entities on my github repository

Comment: @Strawberry does hibernate not allow that? if not, how do you escape it?

Comment: group is a reserved word.

Comment: @Strawberry don't have hibernate setup to test but according to https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=995392 escaping is done in the mapping and not the query